# How to sort a list of integers numerically while retaining value order

Tags: python

Say I have a list `[102, 97, 116, 101]`, and I want to rank their values numerically while retaining the value's position in the list, as in `[3, 1, 4, 2]`. How would I go about this?

Comment: Are the numbers in the input list all unique?

Comment: The numbers are generated from the ASCII values of characters from a string (English word, alphabetic only). So the list can be a range of values, as well as have duplicate values. If two numbers are the same (ie: `[51, 35, 51]` they will be ordered `[1, 2, 3]`). So they are unique in that respect.

Answer (score 3):

Sort an input of indices keyed on a lookup into your existing `list`:

```
>>> mylist = [102, 97, 116, 101]
>>> ranks = sorted(range(1, len(mylist)+1), key=lambda i: mylist[i-1], reverse=True)
>>> print(ranks)
[3, 1, 4, 2]
```

The use of `i-1` as the index is because you used 1-up ranks (while Python uses 0-up indices).

Comment: If you want the element as well as the rank, use `enumerate` instead: `sorted(enumerate([102, 97, 116, 101], 1), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: This can be simplified by using `0` as index and only adding `1` to the result of the lambda function.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak: Huh? The result of the `lambda` is the key value; adding one to it makes no sense. The OP's intended output is 1-up, so you need to add one to the results from `sorted` (not the `lambda`) if you use 0-up indices without subtraction (which would let you use `key=mylist.__getitem__` for a slight speed boost).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible way for lists of unique numbers:

1. Create a copy of the list and sort it (reversed). Call it `sorted_list`
2. Create a third, empty list `result`
3. Go through the input list and find the index of each number in the `sorted_list` list.
4. Append that index to the `result` list.

Given your example data that would result in:

```
input_list = [102, 97, 116, 101]
sorted_list = [97, 101, 102, 116]
result = [1, 3, 0, 2]
```

Add `1` to the indices if you want the result to start at `1` instead of `0`.

---

Implementation:

```
input_list = [102, 97, 116, 101]
sorted_list = sorted(input_list, reverse=True)
result = []
for n in input_list:
    result.append(sorted_list.index(n))

# result now contains [1, 3, 0, 2]
```

Comment: This assumes there are no repeats in the original sequence.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque correct. Hence my comment on the question.

Comment: Please don't name-shadow built-ins; you've done it twice here, for `input` and `sorted`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thx. fixed

Answer (score 0):

We can sort and grab the index of item in the unsorted list:

```
sorted_list = sorted([102, 97, 116, 101])
[sorted_list.index(e) for i, e in enumerate([102, 97, 116, 101])]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[2, 0, 3, 1]
```

If you want to start indexing from 1, simply add one:

```
[sorted_list.index(e)+1 for i, e in enumerate([102, 97, 116, 101])]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[3, 1, 4, 2]
```

Comment: Is this sorting the list n times (n the number of elements in the sequence?)

Comment: @ReblochonMasque good point, if you want more efficiency you can do it once outside the list comprehension and re-use the result